# Typescript get the type of object from object array

Tags: arrays, typescript

In Typescript, I have created a `TiketsItem` and the interface with that `TiketsItem` array. How can I get the type from `arr` which must have `history` key?

```
interface TicketsItem {
    id: number
    status: string
    addedAt: string
    subject: string
    history?: {
        date: string
        message: string
        messageBy: string
    }[]
}

export interface Tickets extends Array<TicketsItem> { }

const arr: Tickets = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subject": "Email   certificate expired",
        "status": "Client response pending",
        "addedAt": "2020-09-23",
        "history": [
            {
                "date": "20-10-10",
                "message": "sjflsjl",
                "messageBy": "client"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "subject": "Issue with Email certificate",
        "status": "Client response pending",
        "addedAt": "2020-09-23"
    },
]

const ticketOne = arr[0]
```

I'm trying to use

```
const ticketOne = arr[0]
type TicketsItemMustHaveHistory = typeof ticketOne
```

but it returns TicketsItem again.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) to make all properties in `TicketsItem` type required:

```
type TicketsItemMustHaveHistory = Required<TicketsItem>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrAQawmAzgSUgFtkBvAKGSuWABMAuZEAVyICNpLrcw4xncjHlFABzLlTi1aEWgEEwQsCJDjqyXMzYArCAkUblYicgAWwHgHsoATwD8jCuvW0+EJSrXOqRCLlxwou6Gnibqvv6BEABCNh7G6gC+ANoAuuSJ5ORgNgAOKOhYOATEALICYAAScABuEJUWYNY2yAC8yABKEACOzMBQsgA8hdh4hBBEAHxZVEA)